Installing magento on wsl, /pub and /setup are not found
Magento is freshly installed on wsl, /var/www/html/mage is visible in browser but /var/www/html/mage/pub and /var/www/html/mage/setup are not displaying in browser with a 500 server error. Any ideas why?

Apply below commands
sudo systemctl stop elasticsearch.service

sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service

After that, You can try the below commands for Magento installation.
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/url/pub" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="db-name" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin@123" --admin-firstname="admin12" --admin-lastname="user" --admin-email="admin12@example.com" --backend-frontname="admin"

